# Show textarea after save

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I am using tinymce. And I have an option to show the tinymce with a radio button(Yes or NO). But The funtion only works on the onchange. But after Save the state(Yes Or NO) the state of the radio button is saved. But the tiny mce is not visible anymore(after the user has choosen Yes) when the user visit the page for the first time.

This is the **view** of tinymce:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDF, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFYes) @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => mailModel.IscheckedPDF,true, new {@class = "MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf" })
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFNo)  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => mailModel.IscheckedPDF,false, new {@class = "MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group" id="MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor">
        <div id="hideLableProduct">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.PdfMessage, new { @id = "hideLable", @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "GeneratePDFMailProductHandler", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage)
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div id="hideButtonProduct">
                <br /><br />  <a href="" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGeneratePDF" name="btnGeneratePDF" formtarget="_blank" onclick="generatePdfPreview('GeneratePDFMailProductHandler'); return false;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"> </i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.PreviewPDF</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the **javascript:**

```
 $(".MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "True") {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
        }
    });
```

Thank you

and if I do this:

```
 $(function () {
        if ($(".MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf").val() == "True") {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
        }
    });  




    $(".MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "True") {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
        }
    });
```

the editor is always visible. Even if you select No and save the state and come back to the form. The tinymce is visble and the radio button is selected as no

Comment: put the rendered html here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should add this in your document ready function like this:-

```
$(function(){
    showHideTinyMce()

    $(".MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf").change(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == "True") {
        $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').show();
      }
      else {
        $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
     }
    });
 });

 function showHideTinyMce(){
        $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
        if ($(".MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf").val() == "True") {
              $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').show();
        }              
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the problem now is that the change doesnt work anymore. If you change the radio button from yes to no or from no to yes. The tinymce will not hide - if you choose for no. So you select no and save the form. Then if you come back to the form the radio button has selection no, but the tiny mce is visible.

Comment: Thank you. But now the radio buttons are not working anymore. you cant swith from yes to no. Nothing happens

Comment: The problem is now that if you select any option of radio button always false is the result

Comment: Does that means radio button change method is triggering and always it shows false?

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution. See my post

Comment: I already had edited my post yesterday.. you should n't write business logic in view.. its bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in document ready.

PSB.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "True") {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you. bUt if you select now Yes, the tinymce is not visible if you come back after save the form

Comment: actaully you hard coded the radio button value during binding, please change to this `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => mailModel.IscheckedPDF,mailModel.IscheckedPDF, new {@class = "MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf" })`

Comment: But then for both the checkboxes? yes and no?

Comment: I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Because it is a partial view, I thought I was not allowed to put any scripts in there. But the solution was to put the scripts in the partial view, like this:

```
@if (!Model.IsCheckedPDFMailForm) {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MAIL_FORM_SUBMITTER_pdfeditor').hide();
        });
    </script>
}
```

and in a seperate jquery file, like this:

```
 $(".MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "True") {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Writing business logic in View is considered as a bad practice.